# Android studio code inspection shell script for integration in CI pipeline

Tags: android, shell, android-studio, code-inspection, dead-code

I am trying to integrate dead code analysis for my android app to improve code quality. I found out the code inspection option that android studio provides out of the box which is giving me an extensive report of unused code and suggested improvements.

I used the Analyze -> inspect code option

[image]

I get the results in studio as follows:

[image]

This is very useful but I want to integrate this code analysis into my CI pipeline so that I can track and trend the warnings that are reported.

I found out a [blog](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/command-line-code-inspector.html) that said I can use the inpsect.sh file that comes with the Android Studio package for the same purpose. The syntax of the command is as follows:

```
sh inspect.sh <project> <inspection-profile> <output> [<options>]
```

I tried to run this command by passing the appropriate parameters given below:

```
sh inspect.sh Users/user1/Documents/androidProject /Users/user1/Documents/androidProject/app/src/InspectionProfile.xml /Users/user1/Documents/inspectionResults -v2 -d /Users/user1/Documents/androidProject/app/src
```

but whenever I try to run this shell script with the required params I am getting the following error:

```
inspect.sh: line 9: exec: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/inspect.sh/../MacOS/studio: cannot execute: Not a directory
```

Spent lot of time but no luck. What am i missing here?

Comment: How did run the command? Include the command line in your question.

Comment: @Darkman i have updated the question with command that I tried to execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the contents of `inspect.sh`, I realized that the script was expecting the absolute path of the script to be passed as the first parameter.

Instead of passing:

```
sh inspect.sh Users/user1/Documents/androidProject /Users/user1/Documents/androidProject/app/src/InspectionProfile.xml /Users/user1/Documents/inspectionResults -v2 -d /Users/user1/Documents/androidProject/app/src
```

I had to pass the absolute path of `inspect.sh`as follows:

```
sh "/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/inspect.sh" Users/user1/Documents/androidProject /Users/user1/Documents/androidProject/app/src/InspectionProfile.xml /Users/user1/Documents/inspectionResults -v2 -d /Users/user1/Documents/androidProject/app/src
```

Finally, I was able to get the XML reports for inspection at `/Users/user1/Documents/inspectionResults`

Answer (score 1):

It's because you didn't specify a parameter for the `-d` option.

> -d    <Specify the full path to the subdirectory if you don't want to inspect the whole project.>

It should be like this:

```sh
inspect.sh 'Users/user1/Documents/androidProject' '/Users/user1/Documents/androidProject/app/src/InspectionProfile.xml' '/Users/user1/Documents/inspectionResults' -v2 -d '/Users/user1/Documents/androidProject/app/src'
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I am still facing the same issue after passing the path of the directory to inspect. I tried without passing the -d option too.

Comment: Is there a directory in `/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio`? `inspect.sh` expects a dir to be there. If not, then it must be a bug in `inspect.sh`. Try updating a newer one.